# Set the selected value of two dropdownlists simultaneously using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, jquery-mobile

How to set the selected value of a dropdownlist to the selected value of another?

The below code shows how to accomplish this correctly.

**ASPX**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" RunAt="Server" DataValueField="ID" DataTextField="ID" AppendDataBoundItems="true"/>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl2" RunAt="Server" DataValueField="ID" DataTextField="TEXT" AppendDataBoundItems="true"/>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$("#<%= ddl1.ClientID %>").change(function() {
    var Code = $(this).val();
    $("#<%= ddl2.ClientID %>").val(Code);
});
```

When using **jQuery Mobile**, however the DataTextField is rendered as a span tag which the above code does not update.

**QUESTION**

How to amend the above code to accommodate for this?

http://jsfiddle.net/E28WW/

Comment: Is your JS / jQuery code in a script element that appears after the select elements in question, or in a document ready handler?

Comment: All the specified code above is on the same page and in the order as above.

Comment: you mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/V6h5e/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the value from first selectmenu, then look for it in the second one. Select it using
`.prop('selected', true);` and then call `.selectmenu('refresh')`.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/spHMG/)**

```js
$(document).on('pageinit', function () {
  $(document).on('change', '#ddl1', function () {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    $('#ddl2 option[value="' + selected + '"]').prop('selected', true);
    $('#ddl2').selectmenu('refresh');
  });
});
```

I used `pageinit` which is equivalent to `.ready()`. It is a special event for jQM.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the help @Omar and for clarifying the differences when using Jquery Mobile over Jquery.

Comment: Can this code be tweaked to work both ways so ddl2 also selects ddl1?
Without the need to duplicate all the code?

Comment: Omar you are a genius. My humble thanks and respect.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the `change` function is actually being called. Is the script you provide the entire contents of the script tag?

The function will not be bound to the event until it is loaded, using the `$(document).ready();` will bind the event to the control.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#<%= ddl1.ClientID %>").change(function() {
        var Code = $(this).val();
        $("#<%= ddl2.ClientID %>").val(Code);
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes this is all the script for this page. Debugging shows the val() is being set correctly and $ is shorthand for $(document).ready in Jquery.

Comment: Please use JQM page events like pageshow etc.. for element events

Comment: Apologies didn't realize that this was a JQM question.

Comment: No my apologies Nunners, for not being clear in my question initially. I did not believe it was relevant to the question however it seems it is the cause of the problem.

Comment: @DreamTeK on jsfiddle it works, in reality, it will mess up your code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468659/jquery-mobile-document-ready-vs-page-events

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @Omar however it is not relevant in my situation as I have ajax navigation disabled due to conflicts with asp.net.

Comment: No apologies needed. @DreamTeK jQM events still fire in absence of ajax navigation :)